# Why does this small vbscript to change desktop background work intermittently, not all the time?

Tags: vbscript, automation, registry, scheduled-tasks

A small VBscript in order to change the desktop background automatically, practically for demo purposes:

```
dim wshShell 
dim sUserName
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
currWallPaper = oShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Desktop\General\Wallpap erSource")
If currWallPaper = "C:\Users\Utsav\Pictures\493889.png" Then
msgbox "OK1"
sWallPaper = "C:\Users\Utsav\Pictures\336180.png"
ElseIf currWallPaper = "C:\Users\Utsav\Pictures\336180.png" Then
sWallPaper = "C:\Users\Utsav\Pictures\1920-1080-278658.png"
Else
sWallPaper = "C:\Users\Utsav\Pictures\493889.png"
End If

' update in registry 
 oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", sWallPaper
' let the system know about the change 
oShell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
msgbox "done"
```

This script works only intermittently, i.e. on executing from command line it will change the background only once in about 4-5 attempts. Any ideas explaining the reason for this behaviour would be most welcome.